React redux state is not rendering wtih React-Router library
I am creating a survey questionnaire form with reusable React components for the page layout with state coming from my Redux store. My state has updated, but the updated state is not rendering properly on the page. Specifically on the review route, my item.value are missing. How can I get values to render?
App.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const feedbackSchema = useSelector((store) => store.feedbackSchema);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFeedback();
  }, []);

  const fetchFeedback = () => {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/feedback',
    })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'SET_FEEDBACK',
          payload: response.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('You had a axios GET error', error);
      });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (item, index) => {
    console.log(item, inputValue);
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_VALUE',
      payload: [item, inputValue],
    });
    history.push(
      feedbackSchema[index + 1]?.route
        ? `/${feedbackSchema[index + 1]?.route}`
        : '/review'
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1 className="App-title">Feedback!</h1>
        <h4>Don't forget it!</h4>
      </header>
      {feedbackSchema.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.key} className="feedback-container">
            <Route exact path={`/${item.route}`}>
              <h1>{item.header}</h1>
              <form>
                <div className="feedback-input">
                  <p className="feedback-topic">{item.topic}</p>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value={inputValue}
                    onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => handleSubmit(item.key, index)}
                  >
                    Next
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </Route>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <Route exact path={`/review`}>
        <h1>Review Your Feedback</h1>
        {feedbackSchema.map((feedback) => {
          return (
            <p key={feedback.key}>
              {JSON.stringify(feedback)}
              {feedback.key}: {feedback.value}
            </p>
          );
        })}
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Store.js
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const feedbackList = (state = [], action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SET_FEEDBACK') {
    return action.payload;
  }
  return state;
}

const feedbackSchema = (
  state = [
    { key: "feeling", route: "", header: "How are you feeling today?", topic: "Feeling?", value: "" },
    { key: "understanding", route: "understanding", header: "How well are you understanding the content?", topic: "Understanding?", value: "" },
    { key: "support", route: "support", header: "How well are you being supported?", topic: "Support?", value: "" },
    { key: "comments", route: "comments", header: "Any comments you want to leave?", topic: "Comments", value: "" }
  ],
  action
) => {
  if (action.type === 'SET_VALUE') {
    state.map((feedback) => {
      if (feedback.key === action.payload[0]) {
        feedback.value = action.payload[1]
      }
      return feedback;
    })
  }
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    feedbackList,
    feedbackSchema,
  }),
  applyMiddleware(logger)
)

export default store;

index.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App/App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import store from './store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);



can you try adding a new review file and use feedback from the useSelector to check if it fetch the updated value. I think currently on route change the state from the redux is not getting fetched

@SakshiMahajan - I thought that was the problem to, but it was actually how I was getting data back from the reducer and that I was actually not saving or keeping the updated state in a variable.

You are mutating state but not returning a new state reference, use return state.map((feedback) => .....) in the conditional.

The state is updated but the UI is not updating because react-redux checks if the data is changed by comparing the address of the data.
In your Store.js file
const feedbackSchema = (state = [], action) => {
    if (action.type === 'SET_VALUE') {
        state.map((feedback) => {
            if (feedback.key === action.payload[0]) {
                feedback.value = action.payload[1]
            }
            return feedback;
        })
    }
    return state;
}

You are returning same data by updating the state. Hence the reducer compares if address of state is equal to address of state. This makes it think no changes are made.
Instead you can do this,
const feedbackSchema = (state = [], action) => {
    if (action.type === 'SET_VALUE') {
       const temp = state.map((feedback) => {
            if (feedback.key === action.payload[0]) {
                feedback.value = action.payload[1]
            }
            return feedback;
        })
    }
    return temp;
}

By returning a new variable temp reducer will understand the changes are made and UI will be updated.

Just FYI, this fails when action.type is any value other than "SET_VALUE", and it still allows a state mutation to occur.

Issue
You are mutating state and not returning new state references.
const feedbackSchema = (state = [....], action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SET_VALUE') {
    state.map((feedback) => {
      if (feedback.key === action.payload[0]) {
        feedback.value = action.payload[1] // <-- mutation!!!
      }
      return feedback;
    })
  }
  return state; // <-- same reference as previous state
}

React works by using shallow reference equality checks and if the state is the same reference as the previous render cycle React won't necessarily trigger a component rerender.
Solution Suggestions
To address this correctly all state, and nested state, that is being updated necessarily needs to be a new object reference.
I suggest the following re-write:
const feedbackSchema = (state = [....], action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SET_VALUE') {
    return state.map((feedback) => { // <-- array.map creates new array reference
      if (feedback.key === action.payload[0]) {
        // Updating this feedback, create new object reference
        return {
          ...feedback,
          value: action.payload[1],
        };
      }

      // Not updating feedback, return current feedback reference
      return feedback;
    })
  }

  // Just return current state
  return state;
}

It is more conventional to use switch statements in reducer functions though, so it could also be re-written to a more standard pattern/form:
const feedbackSchema = (state = [....], action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch(type) {
    case 'SET_VALUE':
      const [key, value] = payload;
      return state.map((feedback) => feedback.key === key
        ? { ...feedback, value }
        : feedback
      );

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

